# Size increases after merging split PDF

Tags: pdf, merge

I am using PDF to be rendered in my application, for various other information of page level (creating swf, xml etc for different o/p format) page level spliting is done and processed.

Environment is Linux (Fedora 8).

Final PDF is recreated using the split PDF but there is drastic increase in size for a few PDF where similar font is used over a large no. of pages.

Using iText and PDFTK output is not satisfactory...
It simply adds the split PDF and final output is same size of individual PDF combined together.

I think optimization and/or shared resources duplication is what I am missing here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PdfTk uses a mighty old (and no longer supported) version of iText. When concatenating PDFs, it uses the `PdfCopy` class. You should use a recent version of iText and PdfSmartCopy. `PdfSmartCopy` stores hashes of all the objects that are added to the new document. This allows iText to reuse objects that already exist.

For more info, read chapter 6 of the book I wrote about iText: http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf (search for PdfSmartCopy)

Comment: iText still is not giving the expected output, in my app i require the information at page level. So i split the PDF extract the information but for merging i am using the original PDF only. It adds to space consumption at server, but serves the problem temporarily.