# Tenfold increase in size of pdf after burst and cat (with pdftk)

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I did `pdftk burst` a document with 300 pages.

I  `pdftk cat` 1 page every 3.

I got a document of 100 pages.

The size of the document increased from 800kb to 11Mb!!!

From this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512328/size-increases-after-merging-split-pdf) I undestand `pdftk` might be outdated. Should I use some other tool?

Answer (score 0):

Are you transforming the burst pages in any way before putting them together? If you are, then you should probably go with another tool as suggested by the question you link to. Otherwise there is no need to burst first, just use a page range like

```sh
pdftk input.pdf cat `seq 1 3 300` output output.pdf
```